# Navbar does not dropdown on tablets

Tags: wordpress, navbar

My site, jrummyapps.com, works fine on computers but if I view the full site on my Nexus10 I am not able to get the dropdowns to work. Is this fixable with something? I am new to tablet sites so I am not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The code located in header.php of the theme folder is,

```
<div id="mainmenu" class="<?php echo siteorigin_setting('general_scale_main_menu') ? 'scaled' : '' ?>">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'main',
            'menu_id' => 'mainmenu-menu',
            'fallback_cb' => 'pitch_fallback_nav',
        ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if this helps or not. As I am not sure if I am able to add in code to the `div`s that it is nested into and have it affect the site. As the site is live, I would prefer to know that it should work before I take the chance of crashing it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following inside your span, li or anchor tag. This causes the tablets to behave better and open the dropdown.

```
onClick="return true"
```

You can also look at bootstrap-dropdown.js on the [Twitter Bootstrap website](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).

Comment: Thanks for that tip but how can I add that into a wordpress site? It does not have any span, li, or anchor tags. I have updated my first post to show some code.

Comment: Sure. Any time you want to customize the HTML generated by wp_menu(), you need to create a custom Walker class in your theme's functions.php. Here is a decent tutorial on extending the walker class. http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

Answer (score 0):

An extra-simple way to add this into your Wordpress site is to wrap the title in your Menu Editor, e.g. `<span onclick="return true"> Page Title </span>`